# Twitter like status message using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter, message, status

I am using this jquery javascript function to show status message,

```
function topBar(message) {
  $("<div />", { 'class': 'topbar', text: message }).hide().prependTo("body")
      .slideDown('fast').delay(4000).slideUp(function() { $(this).remove(); });
}
```

and my css:

```
.topbar { 
    background: #476275; 
    border-bottom: solid 2px #EEE; 
    padding: 3px 0; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: white;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:135%;
    font-weight:bold;
}​
```

I am getting my status message but what it does it inserts a div within the body tag instead i want the message to display out of the body(z index) exactly like twitter (ie) just flow my message from top and hide it... Any suggestion.... Hope you got my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/

If you download the plugin you can change the speed of the fade in/out by amending lines 28 (for fade in) and 39 (for fade out) from `fast` to `slow`

e.g

**line 28**
`_wrap_bar.append(_message_span).append(_remove_cross).hide().insertBefore($('.content')).fadeIn('slow');`

**line 39**

`$('.jbar').fadeOut('slow',function(){`

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur - see amended answer

Answer (score 0):

you can't insert an item before the `<body>` tag--your content needs to be within that, so you should probably have a container element surrounding all of the other elements that you can prepend the message to